# Captions appear out of position in image slider

Tags: javascript, css

I have been working on this JS slider for my webpage. There is something that is slightly off in the format. I cannot seem to figure out where it is.

When it displays the picture with the caption below, there is a space below the caption, and then on the fifth picture, the caption appears at the top of the slider and there is no picture displayed. Here is the code for the JS slider, along with the index.html file that I used to implement it.

[Bottom of Image has grey extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USQIN.jpg)
[image]
[After images appear the slider does this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asLPJ.png)
[image]

```
//Slider JS
    var cssSlidy = function(newOptions) {
    var options = (function() {
        var mergedOptions = {},
        defaultOptions = {
            timeOnSlide: 8,
            timeBetweenSlides: 1,
            slidyContainerSelector: '#slidy-container', // name of slider container
            slidySelector: '#slidy', // name of slider
            slidyDirection: 'left', // options: left, right
            fallbackFunction: function() {},
            cssAnimationName: 'slidy',
            captionSource: 'data-caption', // options: data-caption, alt, none
            captionBackground: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
            captionColor: '#fff',
            captionFont: 'Avenir, Avenir Next, Droid Sans, DroidSansRegular, Corbel, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif',
            captionPosition: 'bottom', // options: top, bottom
            captionAppear: 'perm', //  options: slide, perm, fade
            captionSize: '1.6rem', // same units
            captionPadding: '1.65rem' // same units
        };
        for (var option in defaultOptions) mergedOptions[option] = defaultOptions[option];
        for (var option in newOptions) mergedOptions[option] = newOptions[option];
        return mergedOptions;
    })(),
        CS = this;
    CS.animationString = 'animation';
    CS.hasAnimation = false;
    CS.keyframeprefix = '';
    CS.domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O Khtml'.split(' ');
    CS.pfx = '';
    CS.element = document.getElementById(options.slidySelector.replace('#', ''));
    CS.init = (function() {
        // browser supports keyframe animation w/o prefixes
        if (CS.element.style.animationName !== undefined) CS.hasAnimation = true;
        // browser supports keyframe animation w/ prefixes
        if (CS.hasAnimation === false) {
            for (var i = 0; i < CS.domPrefixes.length; i++) {
                if (CS.element.style[CS.domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName'] !== undefined) {
                    CS.pfx = domPrefixes[i];
                    CS.animationString = pfx + 'Animation';
                    CS.keyframeprefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
                    CS.hasAnimation = true;
                    // determines CSS prefix required for CSS animations
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (CS.hasAnimation === true) {
            var images = CS.element.getElementsByTagName("img"),
                L = images.length,
                fig = document.createElement('figure'),
                who, temp;
            while (L) {
                temp = fig.cloneNode(false);
                who = images[--L];
                // wraps all images in the slider with <figure> tags
                if (options.captionSource === "alt" || options.captionSource === "data-caption" ) {
                caption = who.getAttribute(options.captionSource); }
                who.parentNode.insertBefore(temp, who);
                if (options.captionSource == "alt" || options.captionSource == "data-caption") {
                 if (caption !== null) {
                     content = document.createElement('figcaption');
                    content.innerHTML = caption;
                    // places captions in each <figure> element, if required
                    }
                }
                temp.appendChild(who);
                if (options.captionSource !== "none" ) {
                if (caption !== null) temp.appendChild(content);
                }
            }
            var figs = CS.element.getElementsByTagName("figure");
            var firstFig = figs[0]; // get the first figure inside the "slidy" element.
            figWrap = firstFig.cloneNode(true); // copy it.
            CS.element.appendChild(figWrap); // add the clone to the end of the images
            var imgCount = images.length, // count the number of images in the slide, including the new cloned element
                totalTime = (options.timeOnSlide + options.timeBetweenSlides) * (imgCount - 1), // calculate the total length of the animation by multiplying the number of _actual_ images by the amount of time for both static display of each image and motion between them
                slideRatio = (options.timeOnSlide / totalTime) * 100, // determine the percentage of time an induvidual image is held static during the animation
                moveRatio = (options.timeBetweenSlides / totalTime) * 100, // determine the percentage of time for an individual movement
                basePercentage = 100 / imgCount, // work out how wide each image should be in the slidy, as a percentage.
                position = 0, // set the initial position of the slidy element
                css = document.createElement("style"); // start marking a new style sheet
            // creating css style tag
            css.type = "text/css";
            css.id = options.slidySelector.replace('#', '') + "-css";
            css.innerHTML += options.slidyContainerSelector + " { overflow: hidden; }\n";
            css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " { text-align: left; margin: 0 ; font-size: 0; position: relative; width: " + (imgCount * 100) + "%;  }\n"; // set the width for the inner slider container
            css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " figure { float: left; margin: 0; position: relative; display: inline-block; width: " + basePercentage + "%; height: auto; }\n"; // set the width and size pf the inner <figure> elements
            css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " figure img { width: 100%; }\n";
        if (options.captionSource == "alt" || options.captionSource == "data-caption") {
            css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " figure figcaption { padding-bottom: 0px; position: absolute; line-height: 1.6rem; margin: 0 auto; width: 95.5%; background-color: " + options.captionBackground + "; color: " + options.captionColor + "; font-family: " + options.captionFont + ";";
            var captions = document.getElementsByTagName("figcaption");
            var captionHeight = captions[0].offsetHeight * 2 + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(captions[0]).fontSize, 10);
            if (options.captionPosition == "top") {
                switch (options.captions) {
                    case 'fade':
                        css.innerHTML += " top: 0; opacity: 1;";
                        break;
                    case 'slide':
                        css.innerHTML += " top: -" + captionHeight + "px; ";
                        break;
                    default:
                        css.innerHTML += " top: 0;";
                }
            } else {
                switch (options.captionAppear) {
                    case 'fade':
                        css.innerHTML += " bottom: 0; opacity: 1;";
                        break;
                    case 'slide':
                        css.innerHTML += " bottom: -" + captionHeight + "px; ";
                        break;
                    default:
                        css.innerHTML += " bottom: 0;";
                }
            }
            css.innerHTML += " font-size: " + options.captionSize + "; padding: " + options.captionPadding + "; " + keyframeprefix + "transition: .5s; }\n";
            css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + ":hover figure figcaption { opacity: 1; ";
            if (options.captionPosition == "top") {
                css.innerHTML += " top: 0px;";
            } else {
                css.innerHTML += " bottom: 0px;";
            }
            css.innerHTML += " }\n";
            }
            css.innerHTML += "@" + keyframeprefix + "keyframes " + options.cssAnimationName + " {\n";
            if (options.slidyDirection == "right") {
                for (i = imgCount - 1; i > 0; i--) { // 
                    position += slideRatio; // make the keyframe the position of the image
                    css.innerHTML += position + "% { left: -" + (i * 100) + "%; }\n";
                    position += moveRatio; // make the postion for the _next_ slide
                    css.innerHTML += position + "% { left: -" + ((i - 1) * 100) + "%; }\n";
                }
            } else { // the slider is moving to the left    
                for (i = 0; i < (imgCount - 1); i++) { // 
                    position += slideRatio; // make the keyframe the position of the image
                    css.innerHTML += position + "% { left: -" + (i * 100) + "%; }\n";
                    position += moveRatio; // make the postion for the _next_ slide
                    css.innerHTML += position + "% { left: -" + ((i + 1) * 100) + "%; }\n";
                }
            }
            css.innerHTML += "}\n";
            css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " { ";
            if (options.slidyDirection == "right") {
                css.innerHTML += "left: " + imgCount * 100 + "%"
            } else {
                css.innerHTML += "left: 0%; "
            }

            css.innerHTML += keyframeprefix + "transform: translate3d(0,0,0); " + keyframeprefix + "animation: " + totalTime + "s " + options.cssAnimationName + " infinite; }\n"; // call on the completed keyframe animation sequence
            // place css style tag
            if (options.cssLocation !== undefined) options.cssLocation.appendChild(css);
            else document.body.appendChild(css);
        } else {
            // fallback function
            options.fallbackFunction();
        }

    })();
}
[/CODE]



//index.html
[CODE]

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>change picture</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function displayNextImage() {
            x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
            document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
        }

        function displayPreviousImage() {
            x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
            document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
        }

        function startTimer() {
            setInterval(displayNextImage, 7500);
        }

        function goTo(num){
            document.getElementById("img").src = images[num - 1];
        }

        var images = [], x = -1;
        images[0] = "img/image1.jpg";
        images[1] = "img/image2.jpg";
        images[2] = "img/image3.jpg";
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body class="background">
<div class="body" onload = "startTimer()">

    <header class="mainHeader">
        <nav><ul>
            <li class = "motto"><img src = "img/name.PNG"
                                     style = "width:230px;height:55px;"></li>
            <li id ="l1" class="active"><a href="/McIntireSolutions/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id = "whoweare"><a href="/McIntireSolutions/whoweare.html">Who We Are</a>
                <ul class = "subnav">
                    <li><a href="/McIntireSolutions/values.html">Values</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/McIntireSolutions/leadershipteam.html">Leadership Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/McIntireSolutions/ourteam.html">Our Team</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="l3"><a href="/McIntireSolutions/whatwedo.html">Solutions</a></li>
            <li id="l4"><a href="/McIntireSolutions/industrypartners.html">Industry Partners</a></li>
            <li id="l5"><a href="/McIntireSolutions/governmentclients.html">Government Clients</a></li>
            <li id = "careers"><a href="/McIntireSolutions/careers.html">Careers</a>
                <ul class = "subnav">
                    <li><a href="/McIntireSolutions/training.html">Training</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/McIntireSolutions/benefits.html">Benefits</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class ="logo"><img src = "img/logo.png"
                                   style = "width:55px;height:55px;"></li></ul>

            <div class = "handle" style = "height: 55px;"><img src = "img/name.PNG"
                                     style = "width:150px;height:35px;"> <h class = "three">☰</h></div>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class = "content"> 
            <div id="slidy-container">
              <figure id="slidy">
                <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Transformation: Migrating legacy environments to managed service environments.">
                <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Integration: Creating interoperable environments where legacy systems and new
                                         services interact with disparate sources of data and other services.">
                <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Modernization: Migrate legacy platforms and technologies to cloud environments
                                         including Amazon Web Services.">

                <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Transformation: Converting Ad-Hoc PMO efforts to integrated IT governance.">
                <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Integration: Enabling metrics driven decision making – linking business decisions 
                                         and governance fora with strategy, capabilities, performance, investments to
                                         IT solutions.">
                <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Modernization: Design and created standard implementation profile framework, adopted
                                         by the White House, enabling service integration and re-use.">

                <img srcs="img/image1.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Transformation: Creating market exchanges between government consumers and commercial
                                         suppliers in the Federal workspace, where the government is able to perform source 
                                         selection in one-click">
                <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Integration: Enabling portfolio management decisions through visualization and road
                                         mapping solutions.">
                <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="" 
                     alt data-caption = "Modernization: Develop technologies that directly impact the mission and mission
                                         environments.">

              </figure>
            </div>

        <script src="cssslidy.js"></script>
        <script>cssSlidy();</script>    
        </div>

    </div>
    <footer class="mainFooter">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 <a href="http://twitter.com/cortfisher">McIntire Solutions</a></p>
    </footer>   
    <script>
            $('.handle').on('click', function(){
                $('.mainHeader nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
            })
    </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make a fiddle: jsfiddle.net

Comment: Either show us the live example of the website, or create a jsfiddle

Comment: I cant figure out how to add my images into the jfiddle